# Docker on windows

Tags: windows, docker

I installed Docker on Windows 10
**when i run following command:**

*docker run hello-world*

**I'm getting following error:**
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run
 elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Can someone help me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you the docker daemon is running.  and when you start it make sure you wait long enough for it to be ready.  In addition it states you need admin rights.